# Javascript render timestamp

Tags: javascript, datetime, timezone

I want to render a unix timestamp into a readable format without my browser taking account for my timezone.

So say the timestamp is 1400167800 (05 / 15 / 14 @ 3:30:00pm UTC), and my timezone is +2. How can I render this timestamp as '15:30' instead of '17:30'?

Comment: Take a look at `.toUTCString` or `.toISOString` of _Date_. If you want to build your own output, look at the `.getUTC*` methods. [**MDN**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date#Date_instances)

Comment: Additionally, to convert that timestamp (which is in seconds since unix epoch) for _JavaScript_ (which uses _milliseconds_ since unix epoch) you simply need to multiply by `1000`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [moment.js](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/unix-timestamp/) to render the value in UTC time zone.

Answer (score 0):

Simple

```
var date = new Date().toUTCString();
```